# Using SQLAlchemy to share SQLite between threads throws ProgrammingErrors

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy

I want to use SQLAlchemy as a way to share a SQLite file database between threads. I cannot get it to work. SQLite throws a programming error (see below). But I understand the `scoped_session` and SQLAlchemy pools are supposed to shield the underlying connection for multithread use. 
I tried to disable `check_same_thread`, but this resulted in unpredictable behaviour of my application, including obscure  `InterfaceErrors` about Parameter bindings. 
I tried moving the reference to Session() to the `processSource` method, but this did not change anything and neither did using a `SingletonPool`.

My code:

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
 def __init__(self, threadID):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.session = Session()

 def run(self):
    print("Starting " + self.threadID)
    processSource(self.threadID,self.session)
    print("Exiting " + self.threadID)

def processSource(threadID,session):
    r = session.execute("SELECT etag,modified from feedinfo where feedid=:feedid order by date DESC", {"feedid" : threadID }  ).fetchone()

db_engine = create_engine("sqlite:///feedfetcher.db", echo=False, 
  #connect_args={'check_same_thread':False}, 
  #poolclass=StaticPool 
 )

Session = scoped_session(
    sessionmaker(
        autoflush=True,
        autocommit=False,
        bind=db_engine
    )
)

thread1 = myThread(1)
thread2 = myThread(2)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

The code results in:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 7532 and this is thread id 2712
```

A full stack trace:

```
Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 636, in _fin
alize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 776, in _res
et
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 42
0, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created
 in thread id 7856 and this is thread id 7852
Exception closing connection <sqlite3.Connection object at 0x037735F8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 636, in _fin
alize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 776, in _res
et
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 42
0, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created
 in thread id 7856 and this is thread id 7852

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool.py", line 290, in _clo
se_connection
    self._dialect.do_close(connection)
  File "C:\Users\Timo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 42
6, in do_close
    dbapi_connection.close()
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created
 in thread id 7856 and this is thread id 7852
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace, please?